# Swashbuckle parameter descriptions

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using SwaggerResponse attributes to decorate my api controller actions, this all works fine, however when I look at the generated documentation the description field for parameters is empty.

Is a there an attribute based approach to describe action parameters (rather than XML comments)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With the latest Swashbuckle, or better said at least the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore variant](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) which I'm using, the **Description field for parameters** can now be displayed correctly as output.

It does require the following conditions to be met:

- [XML comments](http://www.wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/) must be enabled and configured with Swagger
- Parameters should be explicitly decorated with either `[FromRoute]`, `[FromQuery]`, `[FromBody]` etc.
- The same for the method type (get/post/put etc.), which should be decorated with `[Http...]`
- Describe the parameter as usual with a `<param ...>` xml comment

A full sample looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Short, descriptive title of the operation
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// More elaborate description
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="id">Here is the description for ID.</param>
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Bar), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[HttpGet, Route("{id}", Name = "GetFoo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo([FromRoute] long id)
{
    var response = new Bar();
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image: Swagger output with parameter description]

Comment: Is there a way to inherit these comments? For example when I have a crudcontroller. And all my controllers (customer, client, orders, ) etc.. inherit from this controller. Can I specify the comments / description for the parameters in the base controller and let my customer controller inherit?

Comment: In additions to the requirements mentioned in the answer, it is also a necessary prerequisite for descriptions to show up to first generate the xml comments for your project via `<PropertyGroup><DocumentationFile>` in your csproj and then register these in your `services.AddSwaggerGen()` via `IncludeXmlComments(filePath);`.

Comment: I get error `FromUriAttribute` could not be found.  Do I really have to install a new package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` just for the decorator?

Comment: @JohnHenckel I believe [FromUri is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.fromuriattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) after AspNet Core 2.2. Perhaps that's why you can't find it? In recent versions you can use `[FromQuery]` and `[FromRoute]`.

Comment: @Juliën thanks, but my error was something else. I had a syntax error in my XML comment.  After I fixed that, the parameter showed up great!! no attribute is required!!

Answer (score 8):

You should confirm you are allowing Swagger to use XML comments

```
httpConfig.EnableSwagger(c => {
                if (GetXmlCommentsPath() != null) {
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
                }
...
...
);

protected static string GetXmlCommentsPath() {
    var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("path to your xml doc file");
    return path;
}
```

You should also check you are generating XML doc for your desired project. Under your desired project **Properties** (Alt + Enter on top of the project or Right Click -> Properties) -> **Build** -> Check **XML documentation file**

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, when using latest version of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (2.1.0)` and `Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen/Ui (6.0.0)`, enable Xml documentation file generation in your project's Build

Then the following to your `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "My API",
        Description = "API Description"
    });
    options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();

    var xmlDocFile = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{_hostingEnv.ApplicationName}.xml");
    if (File.Exists(xmlDocFile))
    {
        var comments = new XPathDocument(xmlDocFile);
        options.OperationFilter<XmlCommentsOperationFilter>(comments);
        options.ModelFilter<XmlCommentsModelFilter>(comments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to point out that from Swashbuckle 5.0 on (and probably all versions of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)  you should be using ```options.SchemaFilter<XmlCommentsSchemaFilter>(comments)``` instead of ```options.ModelFilter<XmlCommentsModelFilter>(comments);```
See: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#transitioning-to-swashbuckle-50

Answer (score 0):

Use `Annotations`. Package is `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations`.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations

Like this.
[description for parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48rwl.png)

Comment: Duplicate answer, adds no new information.